# what is the difference between ProcessStartInfo's UseShellExecute and CreateNoWindow?

Tags: .net, process, windows-shell

If I were to write a console application that starts another console application as a new process, and use the default "UseShellExecute" and "CreateNoWindow" values, the result is that a new command line window appears next to the console application's window:

```
   UseShellExecute=true and CreateNoWindow=false
```

Now if I were to use the following, no new window would be created but the output of the launched process would appear on the window of the application that launched it:

```
   UseShellExecute=false and CreateNoWindow=false
```

And If I were to use the following, neither a new window would be created nor the output of the launched process appear on the window of the application that launched it:

```
   UseShellExecute=false and CreateNoWindow=true
```

But it seems that "CreateNoWindow" has no effect when UseShellExecute=true, so what role does "CreateNoWindow" play when UseShellExecute=true? Does it apply only when the application launched as a new process is a Forms application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It plays no role.  The rule is that CreateNoWindow will only have an effect when:

1. You use UseShellExecute = false so that the CreateProcess() winapi is used to start the program
2. The program you start is a console mode application.

If the app is a native Windows GUI app that creates it own window then you can ask it to not create a visible window with WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden.  There are however a lot of programs that ignore this request.  They should, only way to stop it is through Task Manager.  Next reasonable choice is ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized